# Grails belongsTo cascade on delete when belongsTo specifies multiple classes?

Tags: grails, grails-orm, cascade, cascading-deletes

```
class Owner {
    static hasMany = Dog
}
class Sitter {
    static hasMany = Dog
}
class Dog {
    static belongsTo = [Owner, Sitter]
}
```

My question is: If I create a Dog instance D, a Owner instance O, a Sitter instance S and associate D with both O and S, what happens to O when S gets deleted? Would O still have D? Since it's a cascade-delete, both S and D would get deleted, right? When what happens to O? Would it still have D?

Comment: I think it deletes the instance. However you could actually test it quite easily in a separate project. I'd be curious to know the definite answer myself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have tested it, it follows the cascade rule: if you delete Owner, Dog will be deleted by cascade, but Sitter will remain.

And it's reasonable: Sitter is independent with Owner. It's illogical that Sitter should be deleted along with Owner, just because he has some common properties with Owner.

Comment: I meant, if Sitter gets deleted, would Owner still have a Dog? Or in your example, if Owner gets deleted, would Sitter still have a Dog?

Comment: @Pau: if Sitter gets deleted, the dog also get deleted by cascade. So the Owner will not have the Dog. The same for the other case.

Comment: Is there a way to prevent Dog getting deleted if Owner get deleted? since Sitter still has the Dog.

Comment: @RRK: you can customize hibernate with xml config, or use beforeDelete trigger to remove the Dog from Owner list before delete owner

Comment: there maybe some other Grails-specific ways that I haven't thought about